# What is the "release" stage in gitlab-ci good for?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Can someone explain to me in simple terms what the release stage actually does, and why that is useful?
As for as I understand the official documentation, all it does is create some kind of tag?!

EDIT: (responding to wedm)
I am referring to the stage described on the official gitlab documentation on https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#release
This page describes all the details, but I don't get the big picture: Why are we doing this, what are we trying to accomplish here?

I have taken over a project that has a "release" stage *after* the deploy stage:

```
release:
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  needs:
    - build-release-env
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^v/"
  variables:
    ASSET_URL_BUILD: "${CI_PROJECT_URL}/-/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}/download?job=build-www"
    ASSET_URL_BUNDLE: "${CI_PROJECT_URL}/-/jobs/artifacts/${CI_COMMIT_SHA}/download?job=docker-image"
  script:
    - echo "Creating release for ${CI_COMMIT_TAG} (${CI_COMMIT_SHA})"
    - cat ./CHANGELOG.latest.md
    - |
      release-cli create --name "Release ${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" --tag-name ${CI_COMMIT_TAG} \
        --description ./CHANGELOG.latest.md \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"Complete Build\",\"url\":\"${ASSET_URL_BUILD}\"}" \
        --assets-link "{\"name\":\"Docker image\",\"url\":\"${ASSET_URL_BUNDLE}\"}" \
        --ref ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
```

Comment: "release" is just an example name, a stage can be named however you want. Are you referencing a specific example in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from the [GitLab documentation about releases](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/index.html) (emphasis mine):

> To introduce a checkpoint in your source code history, you can assign a Git tag at the moment of release. ***However, in most cases, your users need more than just the raw source code. They need compiled objects or other assets output by your CI/CD system.***

One common example would be to attach built binaries to a release.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your given example: from the script part it looks like it's creating a [gitlab release](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/) for the project it's run on. Doing that programmatically gives some advantages, as not all options (e.g. timed releases) are available via the web ui of gitlab.